# Variable suddenly goes out of bounds after method call

Tags: c, mud

So I have some really old C code from a MUD I run and I'm trying to get it to run after compiling with a 64-bit compiler instead of a 32-bit compiler. For reference, the current compiler I'm successfully using to compile is gcc 32 3.2.3 (which is from 2003), the 64-bit compiler is gcc 7.3.1.

When I run the game, as the game is booting up and loading various parts of the game into memory, suddenly the variables in the current stack just become unreadable.

Here is part of the function in question:

```c
void reset_zone(int zone) {
    ACMD(do_wear);
    bool items_loaded;
    int cmd_no, last_cmd = 0;
    int mob_load = FALSE; /* ### */
    int obj_load = FALSE; /* ### */
    struct char_data *mob = NULL;
    struct obj_data *obj, *obj_to;
    room_num r;
    struct char_data *tmob = NULL; /* for trigger assignment */
    struct obj_data *tobj = NULL;  /* for trigger assignment */
    int num_items, j;
    bool found;
    register struct char_data *i;
    int player_count;
    int object_max_load;
    int force_load;

    // Set Player Count used for determing item max load values, go no lower than 100 players
    if (top_of_p_table < 100)
        player_count = 100;
    else
        player_count = top_of_p_table;

    for (cmd_no = 0; ZCMD.command != 'S'; cmd_no++) {

        if (ZCMD.if_flag && !last_cmd && !mob_load && !obj_load)
            continue;

        if (!ZCMD.if_flag) { /* ### */
            mob_load = FALSE;
            obj_load = FALSE;
        }

//  sprintf(buf, "SYSERR: Debugging %c %d %d ", ZCMD.command, ZCMD.line, cmd_no);
//  mudlog(buf, NRM, LVL_GOVERNOR, TRUE);

        switch (ZCMD.command) {
            case '*':            /* ignore command */
                last_cmd = 0;
                break;

            case 'M':    /* read a mobile ###, check mob max, % load, and zone faction */
                if ((mob_index[ZCMD.arg1].number < ZCMD.arg2) && //Limit
                    (number(1, 100) >= ZCMD.arg4) &&  //Percent
                    ((zone_table[zone].faction >= ZCMD.arg5 && //Within range
                      zone_table[zone].faction <= ZCMD.arg6))) {

                    items_loaded = FALSE;
                    mob = read_mobile(ZCMD.arg1, REAL);

                    /* Random eq 1 in 5 mobs, if not flagged !random */
                    if (mob && !MOB_FLAGGED(mob, MOB_NO_RANDOM) && number(1, 5) == 3) {
                        num_items = 1;

                        /* Higher level mobs can load multiple items (1-4) */
                        if (GET_LEVEL(mob) >= 30 && number(1, 3) == 3) num_items++;
                        if (GET_LEVEL(mob) >= 60 && number(1, 3) == 3) num_items++;
                        if (GET_LEVEL(mob) >= 100 && number(1, 3) == 3) num_items++;

                        while (num_items > 0) {

                            switch (GET_MOB_CLASS(mob)) {
                                case CLASS_MOB_SMALLSHIP:
                                case CLASS_MOB_MEDSHIP:
                                case CLASS_MOB_CAPSHIP:
                                case CLASS_MOB_SPACE_BEAST:
                                case CLASS_MOB_SPACE_ENGINE:
                                case CLASS_MOB_FIGHTER_PIL:
                                case CLASS_MOB_SPACE_PIRATE:
                                case CLASS_MOB_NAVAL_OFFICER:
                                    obj = load_space_random(GET_LEVEL(mob), FALSE, FALSE);
                                    //obj = NULL;
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    obj = load_random(GET_LEVEL(mob), FALSE, FALSE, FALSE);
                                    //obj = NULL;
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (obj) {
                                obj_to_char(obj, mob);
                                items_loaded = TRUE;
                            }
                            num_items--;
                        }
                    }

                    char_to_room(mob, zone, ZCMD.arg3);
                    load_mtrigger(mob);
                    load_actions(mob);
                    if (items_loaded) do_wear(mob, "all", 0, 0);
                    tmob = mob;
```

Once it calls `load_actions(mob)`, upon returning back from the function, all of a sudden all of the variables in the stack fall out of bounds, I get `Cannot access memory at address 0x7f00656371fb>` for pretty much everything.

For reference, this is what `load_actions()` looks like:

```c
void load_actions(struct char_data *ch) {
    struct char_data *vict, *victim;
    bool found = FALSE;
    char name[20];


    if (MOB2_FLAGGED(ch, MOB2_FOLLOWER)) {
        for (vict = zone_table[IN_ZONE(ch)].rooms[ch->in_room].people; vict && !found; vict = vict->next_in_room) {
            if (vict && IS_NPC(vict) && MOB2_FLAGGED(vict, MOB2_LEADER) && GET_LEVEL(vict) > GET_LEVEL(ch) &&
                are_friends(ch, vict) == TRUE) {
                found = TRUE;
                victim = vict;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if (found == TRUE) {
            sprintf(name, "%s", victim->player.name);
            do_follow(ch, name, 0, 0);
        }
    }

    switch (GET_MOB_CLASS(ch)) {

        case CLASS_MOB_JEDI:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }//end class switch

}
```

I've stepped through this using GDB, and as soon as I exit the `load_actions()` everything becomes inaccessible, any idea why?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I realize some of the styling is horrid, this source code is from like 20+ years ago.

Comment: In such situations I start with commenting out most parts of code to see if it "suddenly" works correctly and then I keep uncommenting small parts until the problem shows again. Then I focus on the part last uncommented.

Comment: What warning level did you use when compiling?  I'd recommend using the highest level and paying close attention to any warnings produced.

Comment: I'm using `-Wall` for warnings